# to.period function keeps the 'missing values'

Tags: r, na

Very new to R, so I hope I don't frustrate anyone.
Putting together pieces from online searches and using quantmode and purr packages, I have the following code to create an xts data frame called `stocks`:

```
symbols <- c("RYCVX","AJA","IEMG")
start <- as.Date("2006-06-22")
end <- as.Date("2020-07-30")

# collect adjusted column of all symbols in one matrix
stocks <- getSymbols(symbols,src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end, 
                     auto.assign = TRUE, 
                     warnings = FALSE) %>% 
  map(~Ad(get(.))) %>% 
  reduce(merge) %>%
  `colnames<-`(symbols)
```

This is daily, but I want to have a monthly matrix, yet still keep the `NA` fields.
I tried this line of code:

```
mstocks <- to.monthly(stocks, indexAt = "last", OHLC = FALSE)
```

but my resulting data frame is shrunk down to the symbol with the least amount of data, since any row with any missing value is omitted, so I end losing data on the more historically rich symbol.

Is there a way I could keep the missing values and have monthly data that, like my daily data, has rows where one symbol is `NA`?

So here is what I get:

```
                    RYCX        AJA        IEMG
2018-12-30        29.3045     4.5523     33.2045     <- first date all symbols have data
...
2020-07-30        34.2344     5.6664     12.2234
```

What I get now with Walts's help:

```
                     V1
2006-06-30           NA
...
2020-07-29        52.66000
```

What I need:

```
                   RYCX        AJA        IEMG
2006-06-30        29.3045      NA           NA
....
2020-07-30        34.2344     5.6664     12.2234
```

All prices are made up

Comment: Can you give an example of what you get versus what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that by monthly data, you mean the adjusted-close price on the last trading day of the month.  To simply the code a bit, I've used `auto.assign = FALSE` so that `getSymbols` returns an xts time-series object rather than placing it in the environment.  I've also used the function `setNames` rather than  `colnames<-(symbols)` which works but is somewhat opaque. To convert to monthly, use `apply.monthly(last)` which takes the last day of each month in the time series. Data for all months is returned including those with NA in some of the time series.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod) 
symbols <- c("RYCVX","AJA","IEMG")
start <- as.Date("2006-06-22")
end <- as.Date("2020-07-30") 
stocks <- symbols %>% map( ~Ad(getSymbols(.x, src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end,
                             auto.assign = FALSE,
                             warnings = FALSE))) %>%
        reduce(merge) %>% 
        setNames(symbols) %>% 
        apply.monthly(last)
```

which gives:

```
> stocks
                 RYCVX    AJA     IEMG
 2006-06-30  21.901295  5.810       NA
 2006-07-31  21.892862  6.260       NA
 2006-08-31  22.643713 18.400       NA
 2006-09-29  23.732025 19.250       NA
 2006-10-31  25.284351  6.160       NA
 2006-11-30  25.908657  6.960       NA
 2006-12-29  26.817636 20.900       NA
```

Comment: Thanks. Your trick certainly cleaned up my environment, but the result is only one column. I need a column for each symbol

Comment: I've updated my post to include the first few lines of the output variable `stocks`.  I don't see how you would be getting only one column with the default column name `V1`. Are you making any changes to the code I posted?

Comment: If you like this answer, you might click accept to let others know that it's a solution to the problem you posted

Comment: To this day, sometimes your code shrunk my results to one column. I figured it must be in "apply.monthly(last)" part of the code, so with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286585/how-to-use-apply-monthly-in-a-zoo-object-with-several-columns) , I modified the line to apply.monthly(apply,2,last) and now it works every time. Don't ask me how